# Destroying an element appended by Renderer2

Tags: angular

I am rendering a external js using this on the OnInit of the component

```
this._renderer2.appendChild(this._document.body, this.script);
```

And when I want to destroy the created element, I can't destroy it using this:

```
this._renderer2.removeChild(this._document.body, this.script);
```

What is the right way to do it?

Comment: why not the way you already use?

Comment: It is not removing the element